# Where can one see which portions of the Buenos Aires underground (aka subte) is above the ground?

Tags: public-transport, maps, argentina, buenos-aires

Where can one see which portions of the Buenos Aires underground (aka subte) is above the  ground ?

Comment: You can see this by riding on the train, but I imagine that's not really what you're after.

Comment: @Arthur'sPass correctly, I'd like to get the information ahead of time. Also I don't want to have to look up each train station on Google maps to see whether they are under or above ground. By the same token I'd like to not to scan satellite maps from Google Maps or anything else that'd be time consuming.

Comment: Per my cursory reading of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Buenos_Aires_Underground_stations, it appears all Subte lines are entirely underground except for lines P & U (which technically are not Subte anyway).

Comment: @lambshaanxy thanks, yes I'm interested in all lines of what is commonly refered to as the Buenos Aires underground/subte, even though it is indeed sometime not underground :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entire Subte network (sans the Premetro Light Rail and Urquiza Line + various train yards) is underground, so there are no major elevated portions of the network.

If you are visiting to see elevated stations, I believe some of the commuter rail lines just underwent considerable grade separation projects, but those are technically not part of the Subte.

Comment: Thanks, yes I've just realised I confused Belgrano (underground) and Belgrano C (overground) stations.